# Amazon Redshift incorrectly rounding up Numeric(9,4) value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, type-conversion

I was trying to load the data e.g. 49.9999 into **numeric(9,4)** column. How ever through copy command it is rounding up the values to **50.00**.

Copy command sample:

```
COPY <table_name> (PRICE_BAND_CODE,PRICE_BAND_DESC,PROD_LEVEL1_CODE,PRICE_BAND_LOWER,PRICE_BAND_UPPER,PRICE_BAND_SEQ)
FROM '<s3 path>/PriceBandDIM.gz'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
delimiter '|'
IGNOREBLANKLINES EMPTYASNULL GZIP NULL AS '\000'
ROUNDEC BLANKSASNULL TRIMBLANKS REMOVEQUOTES
STATUPDATE ON IGNOREHEADER 0;
```

`PRICE_BAND_LOWER` and `PRICE_BAND_UPPER` are having data type as numeric(9,4) but while processing the data it is rounding up the data.

Please let me know how to handle this scenario.

Comment: Does it behave correctly if you exclude the `ROUNDEC` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The ROUNDEC parameter has to go. Rounds up numeric values when the scale of the input value is greater than the scale of the column. By default, COPY truncates values when necessary to fit the scale of the column.

```
COPY <table_name> (PRICE_BAND_CODE,PRICE_BAND_DESC,PROD_LEVEL1_CODE,PRICE_BAND_LOWER,PRICE_BAND_UPPER,PRICE_BAND_SEQ)
FROM '<s3 path>/PriceBandDIM.gz'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
delimiter '|'
IGNOREBLANKLINES EMPTYASNULL GZIP NULL AS '\000'
BLANKSASNULL TRIMBLANKS REMOVEQUOTES
STATUPDATE ON IGNOREHEADER 0;
```

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.